# If bonds are not physical things, what is meant by bond rotation?

Tags: bond

I’m not sure if this is a stupid question or not, but since bonds are not physically there as such, what does it mean when it can rotate? And how do pi bonds prevent rotation if they are not physical?

Comment: Bond rotation implies that there is a change in the relative positions of the nuclei with respect to each other- which looks like as if we have rotated the "bond".

Comment: _Atoms rotate around_ the bond. Come to think of it, you may rotate any everyday object, like a book or a cat. Is the axis of rotation physically there? No, it is a mathematical abstraction. Yet we use it all the time, and not without merit.

Comment: If you are using your hand to screw or unscrew a screw or a wing nut, your hand makes a rotation movement around the axis of your forearm. The forearm is like the bond between hand and elbow. It can rotate..

Comment: Also, covalent bonds are not kind of rod glued to different atoms. But I wouldn't call them not physical. They are physical indeed, else there won't be the molecule. That their description is rather complicated is something else.

Comment: Chemical bonds are physical things.  They are manifestations of  electron wavefunctions.